# Determine the equilibria

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system 
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=x(1-x^2-y^2)-y+\frac{1}{2}xy,\qquad \frac{dy}{dt}=y(1-x^2-y^2)+x+y^2+2x^2,\qquad (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2.
$$
In polar coordinates, $x=r\cos\varphi, y=r\sin\varphi$ this system reads as
$$
\frac{dr}{dt}=r-r^3+r^2\sin\varphi,\qquad\frac{d\varphi}{dt}=1+\frac{1}{2}r\cos\varphi.
$$
Determine the equilibria.

I think there are NO equilibria. Since if $\dot{\varphi}=0$, we get that $r\geq 2$ what implies $\dot{r}\leq -2$.

So, we cannot have $\dot{r}=0$ and $\dot{\varphi}=0$ simultaneously.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you are supposed to consider $x=r\cos\varphi$ and $y=r\sin\varphi$ and study where $dx/dt=0$ and $dy/dt=0$? It seems to lead to $r=0$.

Comment: @mickep Originally, the system was not given in polar coordinates. But the hint was to consider the system in polar coordinates; I will add the original system to my question.

Comment: There is a slight subtlety here, which is that the polar coordinates (r,φ) are not uniquely defined at the origin (x,y)=(0,0) of the plane. Hence what the computations above really show is that there are no fixed points different from (0,0). Then one can check directly that (x,y)=(0,0) is a fixed point, and the exercise is fully solved.

Comment: @Did When looking at the original system, I can see that $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is a fixed point, okay. But how do I see by my calculation in polar coordinates that there are no further fixed points in the original system?

Comment: Well, by the φ˙=0 argument in your post of course.

Comment: @Rhjg: Was the polar form given or calculated?

Comment: I calculated it

Comment: My result of the calculation of polar coordinates is correct (I compared it with the author's calculation), so I think the last summand in the second original equation must be not $2x^2$ but $\frac{1}{2}x€^2$.

Comment: Well, something seems off somewhere.